# Can I make search field with Views?

Tags: views, search

I would simply like to create a search bar (a text field) that when filled out will return a list of a certain content type on a new page.

Right now with Views I have created a search bar (text field) as an exposed filter but it also shows all the content with it. What I want is to have the search bar but have the results content show in a new window when the search bar is submitted.

Can this be accomplished with Views?

Comment: There's this - http://drupal.org/project/views_search but it's for d6. There must be a reason it hasn't been upgraded to d7, like the functionality is baked in now, yeah?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At advanced, the column at the right, in the view config you can set the filters to apear as a block. You could place this at any random page and when submitting you will be send to the viewpage desiplaying the results from the filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use contextual filters and tell the view to display nothing if the filter from the URL was empty.